# SBT directory not found

Tags: git, maven, github, sbt

Following the instructions on https://web.archive.org/web/20160819160137/http://www.aorta-traffic.org/usage/

I downloaded the zip.file of the project and unpacked it and placed it on my desktop
Then, I went to the shell and changed to that specific directory. I also tried the subdirectories
Then, I ran sbt and got a lot of errors

```
[info] Fetched artifacts of
[info] Resolved  dependencies
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]          org.xerial.sbt:sbt-pack:0.3.6 (sbtVersion=1.0, scalaVersion=2.12)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.xerial.sbt:sbt-pack;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:0.3.6
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/xerial/sbt/sbt-pack_2.12_1.0/0.3.6/sbt-pack-0.3.6.pom
[error]   not found: C:\Users\m\.ivy2\local\org.xerial.sbt\sbt-pack\scala_2.12\sbt_1.0\0.3.6\ivys\ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.xerial.sbt/sbt-pack/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.3.6/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.xerial.sbt/sbt-pack/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.3.6/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]         at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.unresolvedWarningOrThrow(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:245)
[error]         at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.$anonfun$update$34(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:214)
[error]         at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:573)
[error]         at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.update(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:214)
[error]         at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:60)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:52)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:102)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:69)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$20(LibraryManagement.scala:115)
[error]         at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:228)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:115)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:96)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:150)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:129)
[error]         at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask0$5(Defaults.scala:2946)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:67)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:281)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:19)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:290)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:281)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.xerial.sbt:sbt-pack;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:0.3.6
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/xerial/sbt/sbt-pack_2.12_1.0/0.3.6/sbt-pack-0.3.6.pom
[error]   not found: C:\Users\m\.ivy2\local\org.xerial.sbt\sbt-pack\scala_2.12\sbt_1.0\0.3.6\ivys\ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.xerial.sbt/sbt-pack/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.3.6/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.xerial.sbt/sbt-pack/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.3.6/ivys/ivy.xml
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The page looks dead, and the project code seems outdated.

sbt-pack_2.12_1.0/ now has versions of sbt-pack from 0.9.0 to 0.12/ (check https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/xerial/sbt/sbt-pack_2.12_1.0/)

Probably you need to update the  dependency on sbt-pack to an actual version.

I'm not sure although, that other dependecies weren't outdated as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Could using an old version of sbt also be a solution?

Comment: Well, perhaps. I didn't follow Scala development, so probably you would need to downgrade the Scala version too. I can't properly estimate what would be an easier task: to upgrade some of the libraries or completely downgrade the build system down to the state of 2015.

I would start from checking if newer versions of code exist (perhaps the development has been forked and continued in some other repositories). If it's not - then *I'd try* to resurrect the code in a newer environment, but certainly your mileage and approaches may vary.

Comment: Please see the [git tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info) about when *not* to use the tag `git`.